# Xamarin Windows Page title font size issue

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

All page titles in my Xamarin Windows Phone application is very large. I couldn't find any solution to reduce the size.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. The solution for me was to update the NuGet package of xamarin.forms to last version (for me it was 2.0.1.6505) current is 2.1.06524 the last stable version.